# Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError when I run a Java class file from the command line in Linux?

Tags: java, class, compilation

I am trying to run a `test.class` file from the linux command line.  I compiled the file using `javac test.java` which produced the `test.class` file.  When I run the command `java test` it throws a class not found exception.  I also tried specifying the package name with the same result.  Here is the output, can anybody help?  I believe my syntax is correct according to Google searches.

```
[root@localhost usr]# java test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test (wrong name: testJava/test)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: test. Program will exit.
```

Comment: What is the declared package in your class? Also, does your directory structure mimic the package declaration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use 
`java  testJava.test` from the parent directory of testJava

Comment: This is how I have done it in the past but for some reason it isn't working.  It was the first thing that I had tried.

Comment: @tkcsam: Does your `usr` directory contain `testJava`, can you please print the content of both `usr` and `testJava` directory using ls command?

Comment: Ahh you lead me to the correct answer!  I didnt have the testJava direcory.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 8):

You need to compile your .java file with javac:

```
  javac MyFile.java
```

Then run the file using java

```
  java MyFile
```

If you're doing this and it still doesn't work, that means you need to make sure the file and the class name inside the file have the same name... so MyFile.java contains

```
  class MyFile
  {
     // ...
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        // ...
     }
     // ...
  }
```

Comment: I did do this.  I compiled and attempted to run it just as you show but it cannot find the class for some reason

Comment: If you make a brand new file using e.g. vi or vim, named MyFile.java, cut and past the above code into the file, save, and do the javac and java lines, do you get the same error? Do this all from a command line in the directory where you save MyFile. Don't use anything fancy. It's hard to know whether or not this is a code problem, a java problem, or an OS/fs problem.

Comment: hm it works when I create a new file like you suggest.  Although your example does not specify a package name...

Comment: as soon as you add a 'package packageName;' at the top of the file, it reproduces the error that I receive.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your class looks like this:

```
package javaTest;

public class test{
    public static void main(String[] a){
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

Then to compile and run the file, you basically do this:

```
$ ls
testJava
$ ls testJava
test.java
$ javac testJava/test.java
$ java testJava.test
Test
```

What this means is that you have to run the class with its fully qualified name, which includes the package name of the class.You also have to do it *from* the directory that conatins the root of your package. (Unless you specify the "root" directory with the `-cp` flag.)

Answer (score 1):

I too had problem initially.

java -cp . Test

Comment: Always forget to put the . in the CP, dunno why they make you put it. Thanks man!! I'll be back in a month or so again :D